# Рекомендуемые конфигурацИИ или конфигурацИЯ?

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Приветствую!
Помогите пожалуйста правильно написать предложение. 
В процессе работы, возник спорный момент в правильном написании предложения. Есть некий раздел в документе под названием "Рекомендуемые конфигурация системы и аппаратные средства"
Данный раздел предлагает(перечисляет) несколько вариантов возможной конфигурации системы (например, если вы хотите стандартное качество, то конфигурация должна быть минимум такой, если среднее качество, то вот такой .. и т.д.), а так же представлены несколько вариантов аппаратных средств
По тому как идёт перечисление возможных конфигураций, я вижу это предложение только в таком варианте "Рекомендуемые конфигураЦИИ системы и аппаратные средства"
Сторонник первого варианта указал на правила:
"< http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05 
п. 2.
Оба существительных "рекомендуемые". >*

Прошу помочь знатоков грамматики!
Заранее Вам очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае действует правило:

> Определение ставится в форме множественного числа:
>         если по смыслу сочетания при единственном числе было бы неясно, связано ли определение с ближайшим существительным или со всем рядом однородных членов.

Но и приведенный вами пример тоже правильный.  Т.к. речь идет не об определении, а числе сущ-го "конфигурация". Если конфигураций несколько, то , естественно, необходимо мн.ч., - конфигурац**ии**. Обратите внимание: в обеих примерах действует одно и то же правило.  Число определения в данном примере не меняется от того, стоит ли конфигурация в мн.ч. или ед. ч.

Answer (score 1):

В первом варианте рекомендуется явно одна конфигурация и аппаратные средства к ней (или независимо от неё) - это противоречит разным вариантам конфигурации. Во втором варианте слово "конфигурации" не очень хорошо воспринимается во множественном числе ("*варианты конфигурации*" мне кажется более ясным понятием; пользователь, видимо, выберет один). Если нужно выразить связь аппаратных средств с выбранным из рекомендуемых вариантом конфигурации, это можно сделать, например, так:

Рекомендуемые варианты конфигурации системы и соответствующие (им) аппаратные средства.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл этих вариантов различен.
"Рекомендуемые конфигурация системы и аппаратные средства"
означает, что в каждом пункте будет предлагаться одна и только одна конфигурация. Например графа "Единица измерения" или "Физическая величина".
"Рекомендуемые конфигурации системы и аппаратные средства"
означает, что в одном пункте можно указать сразу несколько конфигураций одновременно.
На мой взгляд для графы годиться также "Рекомендуемая конфигурация системы и аппаратные средства". Этот вариант предполагает, что заранее неизвестно сколько будет вариантов и будут ли они вообще.